# Create multiple records in rails app with one click

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I'm trying to create an `app`, where a practitioner can add opening days and hours. The problem right now is, that when I hit the `save button`, it only creates one record. It should be creating a record for every day of the week.

So it would be

monday: open 9.00 - close 17.00
tuesday: open 8.30 - close 16.30
etc.

**_form.html.erb**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('input:checkbox').bootstrapSwitch();
  });
</script>

<%= @schedule.errors.full_messages %>
<%= simple_form_for([:clinic, :practitioner, @schedule]) do |f| %>

<table id="modal">
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= f.error_notification message: f.object.errors[:base].to_sentence if f.object.errors[:base].present? %>

  <% Schedule.days.each do |day| %>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="modal-column-left" style="background-color:#aaa;">
        <p>Åbningstider</p>
      </td>
      <td id="modal-column-right" style="background-color:#bbb;">
        <p>Åbent/lukket</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="modal-column-left" style="background-color:#aaa;">
        <h2 style="margin-bottom: 5%;">
          <h2 style="margin-bottom: 5%;"><%= day.titleize %>: <%= Date.today.send(day) %></h2>
          <%= f.check_box :open_or_not, :data => { :size=>'small', 'on-color'=>'success', 'on-text'=>'YES', 'off-text'=>'NO' } %>
      </td>
      <td id="modal-column-right" style="background-color:#bbb;"><%= f.input :open_time %> <%= f.input :close_time %>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
  <% end %>
</table>
<div class="form-actions">
  <%= f.button :submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

**schedules_controller.rb**

```
class SchedulesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_schedule, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


  # GET /schedules
  # GET /schedules.json
  def index
    @schedules = Schedule.all
  end

  # GET /schedules/1
  # GET /schedules/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /schedules/new
  def new
    @schedule = Schedule.new
    @schedules = Schedule.all
  end

  # GET /schedules/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /schedules
  # POST /schedules.json
  def create
    @schedule = Schedule.new(schedule_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @schedule.save
        format.html { redirect_to clinic_practitioner_schedule_path(id: @schedule.id), notice: 'Schedule was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @schedule }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @schedule.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /schedules/1
  # PATCH/PUT /schedules/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @schedule.update(schedule_params)
        format.html { redirect_to clinic_practitioner_schedule_path(@schedule), notice: 'Schedule was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @schedule }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @schedule.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /schedules/1
  # DELETE /schedules/1.json
  def destroy
    @schedule.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to clinic_practitioner_schedules_url, notice: 'Schedule was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_schedule
      @schedule = Schedule.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def schedule_params
      params.require(:schedule).permit(:title, :start, :end, :practitioner_id, :account_id, :open_or_not, :day_of_week, :open_time, :close_time)
    end
end
```

Comment: You´ll want to start by reading [the docs for nested attributes](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) and [`fields_for`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.0.2.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html) and whatever tutorials on the subject you can find. What you are doing is extremely common but one of the harder parts of Rails to learn as there are a lot of moving parts involved.

Answer (score 1):

Read the documentation of [complex forms](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#building-complex-forms).

You will want to attach multiple schedules to the `Practitioner`:

```
class Practitioner < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :schedules
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :schedules
end
```

The Controller

```
  def practitioner_params
    params.require(:practitioner).permit(:name, schedule_attributes: [:id, :open_or_not, :day_of_week, :open_time, :close_time])
  end
```

And in the form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @practitioner do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :schedules do |s| %>
    <%= s.input :open_or_not %>
    <%= s.input :day_of_week %>
    <%= s.input :open_time %>
    <%= s.input :close_time %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

To dynamically add rows use the [Cocoon gem](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon).